Highlight all multiple keywords within a cell, rather than just the first instance
I'm developing a macro that can be run to check the compliance of line item descriptions against client billing requirements.
For example, certain words and symbols shouldn't be included at all in these line item descriptions. All instances of these non-compliant words and symbols should be highlighted to make it easy to see what needs to be removed/updated.
I have the following code which works well to highlight the non-compliant cells.
Unfortunately, it only colours the first instance of a keyword in the array. If there are multiple uses of "training" or ";" in the same cell then any of the subsequent instances in that same cell aren't coloured red.
Sub Highlight_Keywords()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngKeywords As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim keyword As Variant

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngKeywords = ws.Range("N2:N1000")

    For Each cell In rngKeywords
        For Each keyword In Array("Training", "Planning", "Filing", "Scanning", "Photocopying", "Printing", ";", ":", "&", "/")
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                cell.Characters(InStr(1, cell.Value, keyword, vbTextCompare), Len(keyword)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next keyword
    Next cell
End Sub


I've found plenty of examples of VBA code that highlights a single keyword multiple times in the same cell, but haven't come across anything that works to highlight multiple instances of multiple keywords in the same cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


Use a loop to set font color for all instances in a cell
InStr returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.
Use Excel worksheet function Substitute to replace the first instance with the same amount of space.

Microsoft documentation:

InStr function

Sub Highlight_Keywords()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngKeywords As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim keyword As Variant
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngKeywords = ws.Range("N2:N1000")
    Dim sTxt As String, iLoc As Long
    For Each cell In rngKeywords
        sTxt = UCase(cell.Value)
        If Len(sTxt) > 0 Then
            For Each keyword In Array("Training", "Planning", "Filing", "Scanning", "Photocopying", "Printing", ";", ":", "&", "/")
                iLoc = InStr(1, sTxt, keyword, vbTextCompare)
                Do While iLoc > 0
                    cell.Characters(iLoc, Len(keyword)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    sTxt = Application.Substitute(sTxt, UCase(keyword), String(Len(keyword), " "), 1)
                    iLoc = InStr(1, sTxt, keyword, vbTextCompare)
                Loop
            Next keyword
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub


Note that you can use Mid(sTxt, iLoc, Len(keyword)) = String(Len(keyword), " ") to replace the keyword with spaces - no need to use an application specific function for that.

Highlight Keywords in Single Column
Sub HighlightSingleColumnKeywords()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const TOP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "N2"
    Dim INTERIOR_COLOR As Long: INTERIOR_COLOR = RGB(255, 255, 204)
    Dim FONT_COLOR As Long: FONT_COLOR = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Dim KeyWords() As Variant: KeyWords = VBA.Array( _
        "Training", "Planning", "Filing", "Scanning", "Photocopying", _
        "Printing", ";", ":", "&", "/")
    
    ' Define the Keywords' upper limit and an array of each keyword's length.
    
    Dim KeywordsUpperLimit As Long: KeywordsUpperLimit = UBound(KeyWords)
    
    Dim KeywordLens() As Variant: ReDim KeywordLens(0 To KeywordsUpperLimit)
    
    Dim k As Long
    
    For k = 0 To KeywordsUpperLimit
        KeywordLens(k) = Len(KeyWords(k))
    Next k
    
    ' Reference the (single-column) range.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(TOP_CELL_ADDRESS)
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data in column!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    ' Reset colors.
    
    With rg
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    
    ' Return the values of the range in a 2D one-based (single-column) array.
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    
    Dim urg As Range, Value As Variant
    Dim r As Long, KeywordLen As Long, SentenceLen As Long
    Dim SearchStart As Long, FoundPosition As Long
    Dim Sentence As String, keyword As String, WasKeywordFound As Boolean
    
    ' Process.
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' otherwise it'll take 'forever'
    
    ' Highlight fonts.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Value = Data(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            Sentence = Value
            SentenceLen = Len(Sentence)
            If SentenceLen > 0 Then
                For k = 0 To KeywordsUpperLimit
                    keyword = KeyWords(k)
                    KeywordLen = KeywordLens(k)
                    SearchStart = 1
                    Do While SearchStart <= SentenceLen - KeywordLen + 1
                        FoundPosition = InStr( _
                            SearchStart, Sentence, keyword, vbTextCompare)
                        If FoundPosition = 0 Then Exit Do
                        WasKeywordFound = True ' flag
                        rg.Cells(r).Characters(FoundPosition, KeywordLen) _
                            .Font.Color = FONT_COLOR
                        SearchStart = SearchStart + KeywordLen
                    Loop
                Next k
                If WasKeywordFound Then
                    ' Combine the cells into a range union...
                    If urg Is Nothing Then
                        Set urg = rg.Cells(r)
                    Else
                        Set urg = Union(urg, rg.Cells(r))
                    End If
                    WasKeywordFound = False ' reset
                'Else ' no keyword found
                End If
            'Else ' 'Sentence' is blank
            End If
        'Else ' 'Value' is an error
        End If
    Next r

    ' ... to highlight them (cells) in one go.
    If Not urg Is Nothing Then urg.Interior.Color = INTERIOR_COLOR

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Column keywords highlighted.", vbInformation

End Sub

